# How to avoid onsubmit="return validateForm()" to submit the form when the validateForm() have a bug?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

How to avoid `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` to submit the form, when the  `validateForm()` have a bug?

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="eform" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <input type="text" name="text" Maxlength="10000" />
    <input name="" type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>   
<script>
    function validateForm() {    
        if (dosomething) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

But when function `validateForm()` have some code error, such as...

```js
function validateForm() {    
    ifffffffffffff(dosomerthing) { // Creates an error
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The form is submitted automatically...
It displays 1 sec in Chrome console, how can I avoid this???

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

```js
var from = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', validateForm);

function validateForm(event) {
  try {
    error
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="eform" id="form">
        <input type="text" name="text" Maxlength="10000" />
        <input name="" type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your code is work, but can't submit the form.......

Comment: sorry for my poor english, now i can submit the form, but it still have issue in the form, My goal is when the form does not have any error,  I can submit the form, but if the form have error, it not allow submit the form and see the error message clearly, Thank you very much....

Comment: something like this would get the job done then, for some reason it shows an empty `object`, but if you open the `dev console` it shows the actual error

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to execute or stop executing the `form` method with an condition?

if so take a look, it may help you to get going.

```js
function validateForm() {
var val ="errrrr"; // place your error here.
if(val == "err")
{
alert("submit form");
}
else
{
alert("don't submit the form"); //do what you want to do.
}
  
}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="eform" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
            <input type="text" name="text" Maxlength="10000" />
            <input name="" type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```